# need some help on regex in preg_match_all()

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

so I need to extract the ticket number "Ticket#999999" from a string.. how do i do this using regex.

my current regex is working if I have more than one number in the Ticket#9999.. but if I only have Ticket#9 it's not working please help.

current regex.

```
 preg_match_all('/(Ticket#[0-9])\w\d+/i',$data,$matches);
```

thank you.

Comment: It is possible that a better / more efficient answer can be provided, but we won't know until you provide the full input string.  We understand that your input string can be `Ticket#9`, but we don't know what your input string looks like when you have more than one ticket substring to capture.  Please edit your question to clarify your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your pattern `[0-9]` matches 1 digit, `\w` matches another digit and `\d+` matches 1+ digits, thus requiring 3 digits after `#`.

Use

```
preg_match_all('/Ticket#([0-9]+)/i',$data,$matches);
```

This will match:

- `Ticket#` - a literal string `Ticket#`
- `([0-9]+)`  - Group 1 capturing 1 or more digits.

[PHP demo](https://ideone.com/7U1hW2):

```
$data = "Ticket#999999  ticket#9";
preg_match_all('/Ticket#([0-9]+)/i',$data,$matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
print_r($matches);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Ticket#999999
            [1] => 999999
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => ticket#9
            [1] => 9
        )

)
```